# Controller.swift - Line 4334543800 specialized Controller.tableView(_:heightForRowAt: swift error

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I'm getting "
XController.swift - Line 4334543800
specialized XController.tableView(_:heightForRowAt:" error from swift,

I've set a constant height for each cell and confirmed all sections are displayed using the test account, but on live, some user experiences crash on the particular table.

Code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if self.calendarInfo != nil {
        return self.calendarInfo!.topupsSection[section].monthDataArr.count
    }
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    
    return 100.0
    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellCalendar", for: indexPath) as! CalendarCell
    let  monthList = self.calendarInfo!.topupsSection[indexPath.section].monthDataArr
     let data = monthList[indexPath.row]
    
    cell.calendarInfo = self.calendarInfo
    
    cell.vc = self
    cell.setup(data: data)
    
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    
    let object = self.calendarInfo?.topupsSection[section]
    
    let headerView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 80.0))
    headerView.isOpaque = false
    headerView.backgroundColor =  RLColor.backgroundColor()
    
    let separator  = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 5, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 1))
    separator.backgroundColor =  UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
    
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textColor =  UIColor.init(named: "black")
    label.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 25, width: headerView.frame.width-10, height: headerView.frame.height-10)
    label.text = String(object!.header)
    
    
    headerView.addSubview(separator)
    headerView.addSubview(label)
    
    
    return headerView
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    60
}
```

Does anyone know the cause of the issue?

Comment: Please provide more info and code snippet

Comment: @drfalcoew Thanks. I've added (now) to the question section.

Comment: In your last function you are missing a return keyword. "return 60.0" instead of just "60".  I will keep looking

Comment: Can you send picture of full error from your console please?

Comment: I'm unable to re-create from my end, but some user is experiencing with app crash, when the particular page is opened.

Answer (score 1):

The only code here that should get crash is in your `cellForRowAt` method in this line.

```swift
 let data = monthList[indexPath.row]
```

because I don't see the method `numberOfSections` in your code and you have used `indexPath.section` and `indexPath.raw` in your delegates. which should get crashed causing index out of bounds exception.

Assuming you have a data source like this.

```swift
let dataSource = [[String]]()
```

Then your delegate methods should look like this.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
     return dataSource.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return dataSource[section].count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let data = dataSource[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
     
   //your code     
}
```

Comment: Thanks also for the height issue do you have any solution?
In my case I need to render different type of data based on the content value,

Comment: I don't see any problem with your heightForRowAt method. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: We have different content based on some validation, so if a value is met then a button could be added along with the label, also those could hide with the same condition.

Comment: To dynamically update the layout of the view you have to reload the tableview once you hide or show some views. without it tableview won't layout the height properly

Comment: is it tableBeginUpdate? and end?

Comment: If you are doing multiple updates at a time like deleing some views adding some cells and modifying another cell then you can do it inside begin and end update. but if you doing a single update just reloading is enough.

Comment: Will do bother. thanks for your help